# Which was the original color of Piccolo's blood in the manga?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Recently, it was told that in the next Dragon Ball Super movie, Piccolo was going to be featured with the original color of his skin in the manga, which had yellow spots instead of the pink ones he had in the anime series.

Now how about the blood? Piccolo it is apparently shown with blood in 3 different colors in the anime, red, purple and green.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Which was the original color of Piccolo's blood in the manga? Is there any source material or colored manga page which shows this?

Comment: Are you sure the fluid spilling out during regenaratioin meet the criteria of "blood"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1085015945) asks the same question, and the answer is that the anime is simply inconsistent. ([This](https://dragonball-plus.net/piccolo-blood-color/) seems to give info on how it changed as the story goes.)

[This page](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%8A%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E6%98%9F%E4%BA%BA) says it is purple, which I feel is reasonable. I cannot find any source on whether it is mentioned in the manga. Remember that the original manga is monotone, so the color is not knowable unless explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Not sure, there might be some pages or source books in colors, otherwise why do they say Piccolo skin spots are yellow in the manga, I doubt in the manga it is mentioned in text they are yellow

Comment: Yes there are color pages once in a while (maybe a few pages per 5 episodes, it varies greatly). So  anything that stays long enough has chance of getting depicted. Possibly there were pages where Piccolo's blood is in color, simply I don't remember. Also I believe there is a colored version published, but it is not exactly original (surely it is not the author who did the coloring).